# Javascript greedy regex appears non-greedy

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'd like to match a three-part string. The first part consists of one or more `a` characters, the second part consists of one or more `b` characters, and the third part consists either of zero or more `c` characters or zero or more `C` characters, but not a mix of `c` and `C`.

As such, I wrote the following regular expression:

```
/a+b+(C*|c*)/
```

And immediately noticed that it fails to greedily match the trailing `c`s in the following string:

```
aaaaabbcc
```

Wrapping the inner clauses of the or clause does not fix the unexpected behavior:

```
/a+b+((C*)|(c*))/
```

But interestingly both regular expressions match the following, where the `C` characters match the first clause of the or:

```
aaaaabbCC
```

The following regular expression captures the semantics accurately, but I'd like to understand why the original regular expression behaves unexpectedly.

```
/a+b+(([Cc])\2*)?/
```

Comment: Do you mean it does not work because the `c`  is not matched? However, `C*` did, that is why `c*` did not even get tested.

Comment: Ah, yes - I should clarify that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because first it tries `C*`, which matches the empty string, so it has satisfied the or clause. Then it won't try to check if `c*` can match more characters.

Here's a regular expression which does match the string as intended:

```js
/a+b+(C+|c+)?/
```

That is, if it finds a `C` it will match as many more `C` as possible, if it finds a `c` it will match as many more `c` as possible. But finding `C` or `c` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the * outside of the bracket!

Comment: No, that would match `aaaaabbcCcCc`, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = "aaaaabbc";

// if you want to pick up c
console.log(/a+b+(c|C)*/.exec(input).pop());
```

Comment: No, that would match `aaaaabbcCcCc`, which I do not want.

Comment: Yep, I realized it was a little lacking in detail. The point is that the regex appears to be treating the two clauses of the or clause inconsistently.

Comment: If you have a critique of my question, please make a specific comment. I have read that page in the past, and merely linking to it does not help me improve my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, probably you need to pick up the `c`, probably all the string, probably the `c` could be optionally matched... I can't help you, the question is your, so, you need to clarify what you want.